# how to know the current coordinates of all vertices using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am doing a program using Visual C++ and OpenGL. First, this program loads a .obj file (for example a cube) and then, rotates this object to any angle.

After the rotation, I would like to know the new coordinates (x, y, z) of all vertices of this object.

How can I do that using OpenGL?

I just want to create a new .obj file but having new values for all vertices.

The new .obj file must show initially the same object but having that rotation.

EDIT:
In this moment, I am able to load the .obj file, then, rotate that object without any problem. Everything is working perfect up to this point. However I do not know how can I read the new coordinates reached by all vertices after the rotation.

Comment: Hi Oscar.  You'll get more help if you show the data you're working with, what solutions you've tried so far and then identify why that solution is not working.  E.g. "here is my data, when I try this transformation only the x and y vertices are rotated"

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you very much for your comment.  In this moment, I am able to load the .obj file, then, rotate that object without any problem.  Everything is working perfect up to this point.

However I do not know how can I read the new coordinates reached by all vertices after the rotation.

Comment: As part of rendering the rotated cube, your program must have set up transformation matrices. Figure out how to extract this matrix from your current code and apply it to each vertex.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a model matrix associated with your cube. When you rotate your model matrix your cubes orientation will change, but you notice that this has no effect on the cubes vertex positions. A simple way to obtain these new rotated vertices is to iterate through all your vertices multiplying the model matrix with each position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
{
    // first convert each vertex position to a vec4 to allow for matrix multiplication
    vec4 pos(vertices.at(i).Position, 1.0f);
    // multiply vec4 vertex by the model matrix
    vec4 modelPos = model * pos;
    // convert back to a vec3
    vec3 newPos(modelPos[0], modelPos[1], modelPos[2]);
    // store it in a new vector
    updatedVertices.at(i).Position = newPos; 
    
}
```